# Button button = findViewById(R.id.button) automation in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to automatically create member associated with XML button in Android studio?

Something like I ctrl-click onto button id and it automatically creates correct

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button)
```

Comment: Android Data Binding didn't solved it? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: It's bidirectional, You can use ObservableFields to notify view that model state was changed.

Answer (score 1):

`Butterknife` is a light weight library to inject views into Android components.
visit these link to understand more about it.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidButterknife/article.html

http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

The `@Bind` annotation allow to inject views and performs the cast to the correct type for you. The `@@OnClick(R.id.yourid)` annotation allows to add `OnClickListener` to a view. You can optional define the method parameter of the view in case you want it injected.

Annotate fields with `@BindView` and a view ID for Butter Knife to find and automatically cast the corresponding view in your layout.

```
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
  @BindView(R.id.title) TextView title;
  @BindView(R.id.subtitle) TextView subtitle;
  @BindView(R.id.footer) TextView footer;

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    // TODO Use fields...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a plugin called android code generator https://github.com/tmorcinek/android-codegenerator-library you right click on the xml file select generate it will assign fields to actual objects (findViewById() method) , you won't need to install libraries in the code and there is no compile time annotations , I find this as a cleaner solution .